# Docker Error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED using FastAPI

Tags: api, docker-compose, fastapi

I am trying to deploy an API with docker-compose. I am using FastAPI and I keep getting this error when I try to access the localhost page. If I don't use the docker-compose it works flawless. All my files are in the same directory.

Here is the *Dockerfile*

```sh
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./ ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload" ]
```

And here is the *docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: '2.2'

services:
  api:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - './requirements.txt:/app'
```

And this is the error message I get on the browser:

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Are you sure that the port 8000 is not in use by another process? The answer by @β.εηοιτ.βε seems right, so it may some other system-related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing a port does not means that it is published to your host.

> The `EXPOSE` instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the `-p` flag on `docker run` to publish and map one or more ports, or the `-P` flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports.

*<sup>Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose</sup>*

So, you also need to publish it in your *docker-compose.yml*:

```yaml
version: '2.2'

services:
  api:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./requirements.txt:/app
    ports: 
      - 8000:8000
```

Comment: I am running with the docker-compose up command. And it isn't working. Should I try another command?

Comment: Did you do a down before you trying to do up again?

Comment: No. But I just tried and still got the same error.
The same code is running on my friends computer, he uses linux though.

Comment: What does `docker compose ps` gives you?

Comment: It's giving me this

Comment: ```Name                   Command            State    Ports
---------------------------------------------------------------
wattio_teste_api_1   uvicorn main:app --reload   Exit 0```

Comment: Can't format it right, but I think you can understand hahaha

Comment: So, this is the reason, your container has existed as it should have. Are you sure your command is what that other person do have, really? You should try with `CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]`, rather

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243664/discussion-between-luccas-and---).